# Create Airflow DAG to run a Shell Script containing multiple spark submit commands but execution should stop as soon as any command gives an error

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a shell script in a server where I am supposed to execute the Spark Submit Commands.
But all the commands point to the same JAR and having multiple classes of Spark Scala.

And most of the classes are dependent on the previous class.
Which means that the commands should run in a sequential order and none of the commands should be skipped.

So if in case one of the spark submit command fails or gives an error, the rest of the commands should not run.

Can this be done using Airflow?

I have only created DAG which will run the whole Shell Script but I am not able to come up with the solution as to how to make sure that the Job is stopped if an error is encountered during the running of any Spark Submit Command.

I have used BashOperator for the above.

Comment: Show what you already have.